# How to animate 2 Views Together smoothly?

Tags: android, animation

[image]

I have 2 LinearLayout. Lets say they are **Left Panel** and **Main Panel** as you can see in the picture. I am using an animation to hide left panel. This is what I use:

```
<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```

And I use **android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_panel"** on main panel to hold it right of the left panel. Problem is when I use animation to hide left panel, main panel just jumps to starting point. And when I use an animation to show up left panel again, main panel jumps to ending point.

So how can I move these 2 views together smoothly ?

Comment: You need to use animation on both the panels.

Comment: well i cant use same animation on main panel so what i should use on it ?

Comment: you can try sliding it towards right, maybe? Are these two panels visible at the same time?

Comment: Which view are you animating the XML animation on? The left or main panel? If you're trying to hide the left panel, don't you want `fromXScale="1.0"` instead of `fromXScale="0.0"`? This won't fix your original problem exactly because your problem is that an `Animation` doesn't necessarily update the layout of the `View` they animate on which is why it looks like it jumps. If you are targeting Android 3.0+ I would recommend you look into the `ObjectAnimator` class.

Comment: just winging it here.But have you tried animateLayoutChanges tag in xml?

Answer (score 1):

In stead of using scale animation, you can do it by using the slide (translate) animation. When the event (here button click) is triggered, set the animation of both the panels to slide towards left. You can put a reverse animation to slide them back.

Here is how I did it.

**AnimActivity**

```
public class AnimActivity extends Activity {

    View leftPanel, rightPanel;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_anim);

        leftPanel = findViewById(R.id.left_panel);
        rightPanel = findViewById(R.id.right_panel);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_animate);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                leftPanel.startAnimation(
                    AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimActivity.this,R.anim.slide_left));
                rightPanel.startAnimation(
                    AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimActivity.this,R.anim.slide_left));
            }
        });
    }       
}
```

**slide_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillEnabled="true" android:fillAfter="true" >
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-200.0"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

**activity_anim.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_panel" 
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFD94E4E"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/right_panel" 
        android:layout_width="420dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF242325"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_animate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Animate" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**NOTE**

There is a huge problem with this approach and that is **I have set fixed widths to the left and the right panels**. But I don't know how to resolve this. Sorry for this, but hope this helps.

Comment: I ll try this one. It seems perfect thnx alot

Answer (score 0):

You can use Navigation Drawer for left layout

http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/03/android-sliding-menu-navigation-drawer.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

EDIT:

This one is easy to implement

http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/06/android-sliding-navigation-drawer-example.html

also you can find many useful examples at this link

https://github.com/Trinea/android-open-project/tree/master/English%20Version

Comment: This also looks perfect. Thnx a lot for sharing

Comment: Welcome. If this answer works for you kindly mark it as answer so that others get benefit from this :) .